# Caputuring Folder Screenshot by giving path using C#

Tags: automation, directory, screenshot

I have a requirement for automating Folder File check that we are doing daily basis manually.The requirement is like daily some new folder->files would be created in the server paths mentioned in the D list.currently we have to go there and find it whether the particular folder and files has been generated.So the deal is capturing the screenshot of the each folders and save it in the path mentioned.I need to make an application that would go to each folder generated on today date and get a screenshot of the same.
I found some articles in stack over flow,but it doesn't explain going to one specific folder and getting a screenshot.

Any help would be well appreciated!!!!

Comment: Screenshot? What for? What OS is that? Isn't it better to simply recursive scan directories and get everything you need to know automatically? Screenshot of folder? Sounds really silly, sorry.

Comment: @ Flash Thunder - OS is Windows Server 2008 R2.I know it can  be done using directory class,but the management says they need the screenshot of it :)
-Windows Explorer that is

Comment: screenshot of Windows Explorer? or command line result in terminal? or maybe totalcmdr?

Comment: @Renji: Does management know what a "screenshot" is? In order to capture that, you need a "screen." So this task will require an active console. And it's not going to be so much of a programming task as just a system automation task (opening a folder in Windows Explorer, taking a screen shot, saving). The tools for that are much less sophisticated and much less reliable. Management would get a *lot* more value out of a simple report of the results either run by the process which generates the results or by some new scheduled process. As mentioned in a previous comment, this approach is silly.

Comment: Yes,Its windows explorer not cmd prompt.

Comment: @Renji: If you're intent on this approach, then what you're looking for is called Windows UI Automation.  This link may help get you started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Automation.aspx